# What type should I catch if I throw a string literal?

Tags: c++, linux, exception, g++

I am writing a pretty simple application in C++ using g++ under Linux and I am trying to throw some raw strings as exceptions (yes, I know, its not a good practise).

I have the following code (simplified):

```
int main()
{
  try
  {
    throw "not implemented";

  }
  catch(std::string &error)
  {
    cerr<<"Error: "<<error<<endl;
  }
  catch(char* error)
  {
    cerr<<"Error: "<<error<<endl;
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    cerr<<"Unknown error"<<endl;
  }
}
```

And I get `Unknow error` on the console. But if I static cast the literal string to either `std::string` or `char *` it prints `Error: not implemented` as expected. My question is: so what is the type I should catch if I don't want to use static casts?

Comment: Stupid question: does anyone throw things that do not inherit from `std::exception` in real code ? (Apart from the `SuicideException`, and no, it's not derision :p)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to catch it with `char const*` instead of `char*`. Neither anything like `std::string` nor `char*` will catch it.

Catching has restricted rules with regard to what types it match. The spec says (where "cv" means "const/volatile combination" or neither of them).

> A handler is a match for an exception object of type E if
>
> - The handler is of type cv T or cv T& and E and T are the same type (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), or
> - the handler is of type cv T or cv T& and T is an unambiguous public base class of E, or
> - the handler is of type cv1 T* cv2 and E is a pointer type that can be converted to the type of the handler by either or both of
>
>   - a standard pointer conversion (4.10) not involving conversions to pointers to private or   protected or ambiguous classes
>   - a qualification conversion

A string literal has type `char const[N]`, but throwing an array will decay the array and actually throws a pointer to its first element. So you cannot catch a thrown string literal by a `char*`, because at the time it matches, it needs to match the `char*` to a `char const*`, which would throw away a const (a qualification conversion is only allowed to *add* const). The special conversion of a string literal to `char*` is only considered when you need to convert a string literal specifically.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding `const` to the types you're catching, `const char*`  (possibly `const char* const`).

Comment: Or my personal fav: `char const*`

Comment: @Martin: English speakers seem to have some difficulty with the `const` in suffix position for some reason :)

Answer (score 4):

The exact type of a string literal is an array of const characters (`const char [15]` for your example, since the NUL terminator is included). The array decays to `const char*` when thrown, which is independent of the length.

Answer (score 2):

The type should be `const char[15]` or `const char*`.

However, while the language does not forbids you throwing any type value, you should not be raising native data types as exception. Instead, you want to raise an `std::exception()` instance, or creating your own exception class.

Answer (score 2):

The type of a string literal is `char const *`. There's a (deprecated) conversion to `char *` provided for backward compatibility with existing code (but you still have to treat it as `const` -- any attempt at modification gives UB).

As such, code like this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  try
  {
    throw "not implemented";

  }
  catch(char const *error)
  {
    cerr<<"Error: "<<error<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to catch something that is a const.  The following will work:

catch(const char* error)
  {
    cerr

Answer (score 1):

Check out the section 2.14.5 of the standard specification, it treats types and kinds of string literals on 3 pages. Don't do what you started to do, just say:

```
throw std::exception("not implemented");
```

along with proper

```
catch (std::exception& pEx)
```

Is there something wrong with this "normal" approach...?